# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined (index):21 initialize ( Google Maps API ). Also cannot change the background url

Tags: javascript

I continue to receive a Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined (index):21 initialize ( Google Maps API ).  Also cannot change the background url.

```js
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Grayscale Bootstrap Theme (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

// jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
function collapseNavbar() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
}

$(window).scroll(collapseNavbar);
$(document).ready(collapseNavbar);

// jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle active' && $(this).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle') {
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
  }
});

// Google Maps Scripts
var map = null;
// When the window has finished loading create our google map below
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(40.855929, -73.8651));
});

function init() {
    // Basic options for a simple Google Map
    // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
    var mapOptions = {
        // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
        zoom: 15,

        // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.8545, -73.8645), // New York

        // Disables the default Google Maps UI components
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        draggable: false,

        // How you would like to style the map.
        // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
        styles: [{
            "featureType": "water",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#000000"
            }, {
                "lightness": 17
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "landscape",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#000000"
            }, {
                "lightness": 20
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.highway",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#000000"
            }, {
                "lightness": 17
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.highway",
            "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#000000"
            }, {
                "lightness": 29
            }, {
                "weight": 0.2
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.arterial",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#000000"
            }, {
                "lightness": 18
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.local",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#000000"
            }, {
                "lightness": 16
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#000000"
            }, {
                "lightness": 21
            }]
        }, {
            "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "on"
            }, {
                "color": "#000000"
            }, {
                "lightness": 16
            }]
        }, {
            "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "saturation": 36
            }, {
                "color": "#000000"
            }, {
                "lightness": 40
            }]
        }, {
            "elementType": "labels.icon",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "transit",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#000000"
            }, {
                "lightness": 19
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#000000"
            }, {
                "lightness": 20
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#000000"
            }, {
                "lightness": 17
            }, {
                "weight": 1.2
            }]
        }]
    };

    // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map
    // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

    // Create the Google Map using out element and options defined above
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

    // Custom Map Marker Icon - Customize the map-marker.png file to customize your icon
    var image = 'img/map-marker.png';
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.8555, -73.8651);
    var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
}
```

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Grayscale v1.1.1 (http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale)
 * Copyright 2013-2016 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap/blob/gh-pages/LICENSE)
 */
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Lora", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0 0 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
p {
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  p {
    margin: 0 0 35px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.6;
  }
}
a {
  color: #42DCA3;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1d9b6c;
}
.light {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.navbar-custom {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  font-size: 12px;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:active {
  outline: none;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.navbar-custom a {
  color: white;
}
.navbar-custom .nav li a {
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:active {
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
  outline: none;
}
.navbar-custom .nav li.active a {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.navbar-custom .nav li.active a:hover {
  color: white;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-custom {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out, padding 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out, padding 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out, padding 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
    padding: 0;
    background: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  }
}
.intro {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: url(/New/img/volcano.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
.intro .intro-body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.intro .intro-body .brand-heading {
  font-size: 40px;
}
.intro .intro-body .intro-text {
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .intro {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .intro .intro-body .brand-heading {
    font-size: 100px;
  }
  .intro .intro-body .intro-text {
    font-size: 26px;
  }
}
.btn-circle {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 100% !important;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.btn-circle:hover,
.btn-circle:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.btn-circle i.animated {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}
.btn-circle:hover i.animated {
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  -moz-animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  0 {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
.content-section {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.download-section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  color: white;
  background-image: url(../img/downloads-bg.jpg);
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .content-section {
    padding-top: 250px;
  }
  .download-section {
    padding: 100px 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 250px;
  }
}
.btn {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.btn-default {
  border: 1px solid #42DCA3;
  color: #42DCA3;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
  border: 1px solid #42DCA3;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: #42DCA3;
}
ul.banner-social-buttons {
  margin-top: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  ul.banner-social-buttons {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  ul.banner-social-buttons li {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  ul.banner-social-buttons li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
footer {
  padding: 50px 0;
}
footer p {
  margin: 0;
}
::-moz-selection {
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
::selection {
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
img::selection {
  background: transparent;
}
img::-moz-selection {
  background: transparent;
}
body {
  webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Makan Fofana | Website & Mobile Application Developer </title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link href="css/grayscale.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                    Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
                    <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i> <span class="light">M.F.</span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Intro Header -->
    <header class="intro">
        <div class="intro-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                          <h1 class="brand-heading">Welcome</h1>
                        <p class="intro-text">Makan Fofana | Website & Mobile Application Developer </p>
                        <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- About Section -->
    <section id="about" class="container content-section text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <h2>About Me</h2>
                  <p>I have had the opportunity to take part in a variety of jobs & internships throughout my life and greet all adversity with a positive attitude. I enjoy learning new natural & formal languages. </p>
                <br>
                <h3> Formal Languages & Skills </h3>

                  <ul>

                      <li style="list-style: none;"> HTML/CSS </li>
                      <br>

                      <li style="list-style: none;"> JavaScript & JQuery </li>
                      <br>

                      <li style="list-style: none;"> Ajax </li>
                      <br>

                      <li style="list-style: none;"> Java </li>
                      <br>

                      <li style="list-style: none;">PHP</li>
                      <br>

                      <li style="list-style: none;"> Objective-C & Swift 2.0 </li>
                      <br>

                      <li style="list-style: none;"> BootStraps </li>
                      <br>

                      <li style="list-style: none;"> Python </li>
                      <br>

                      <li style="list-style: none;"> Microsoft Suite </li>
                      <br>

                      <li style="list-style: none;">Adobe Dreamweaver, PhotoShop & InDesign </li>
                      <br>

                  </ul>

                  <br>
                  <br>
              <h3> Natural Languages</h3>

                  <ul>

                          <li style="list-style: none;">Proficient in French</li>
                          <br>

                          <li style="list-style: none;">Intermediate in Portuguese </li>
                          <br>

                 </ul>
                    <!--Anchors turn letters green -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Contact Section -->
    <section id="contact" class="container content-section text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                  <h2>Contact</h2>
                <p>Have any projects you need assistance with? Bring your ideas to life by emailing me below.</p>
                <p><a href="mailto:mfofanaT99@gmail.com">mfofanaT99@gmail.com</a>
                </p>
                <ul class="list-inline banner-social-buttons">

                    <li>
                        <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/115487988117990190953/posts" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Google+</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Map Section -->
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container text-center">
          <p id="copy">&copy; 2016 Makan Fofana.</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Maps API Key - Use your own API key to enable the map feature. More information on the Google Maps API can be found at https://developers.google.com/maps/ -->
    <script async type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIHERE"></script>



    <!-- Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/grayscale.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined (index):21 initialize ( Google Maps API )

Comment: RECEIVING THE ERROR MESSAGE BECAUSE OF A DIFFERENT JS FILE PERTAINING TO THE GOOGLE ON THE SECOND TO LAST LINE, RIGHT AFTER THE NULL;

Comment: body").stop().animate({scrollTop:$(t.attr("href")).offset().top},1500,"easeInOutExpo"),e.preventDefault()})}),$(".navbar-collapse ul li a").click(function(){"dropdown-toggle active"!=$(this).attr("class")&&"dropdown-toggle"!=$(this).attr("class")&&$(".navbar-toggle:visible").click()});var map=null; (RIGHT HERE ON IS WHERE THE ERROR IS SAID TO BE) google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,"load",init),google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,"resize",function(){map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(40.67,(-73.94)))});

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a valid API key. You can see the error in console - `Google Maps API error: InvalidKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key-map-error`.

First get a developer key and put it in place of **APIHERE** in line `<script async type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIHERE"></script>`

`

Comment: Yes I have one and have done that already. I am currently experiencing a "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined" error in the code line a a sited above.